# What is Unreal equivalent of Unity gameObject.parent?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

In the Unreal Blueprint Editor I have a hierarchy of components with a *Scene* parent and Pose Mesh child. I can get the component in Unreal through `GetParentComponents()`, but this returns an *array* while I just need the *Scene* component and not every parent. `GetOwner()` also doesn't return the direct parent.

If I have **PoseableMesh** component, how do I get the **offset** scene component?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a `Get Attach Parent` node, with **PoseableMesh** as **Target**.

From the documentation:
[image]